# Animations with time delay for each child element ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, css-transitions, ionic2

i am add animation effect using [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/) i need to time delay of the each child element

for the referral add image

[image]

How to add time delay in ionic 2 or Angular2 ?
also referred **[this](http://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html)** to implement in ionic2

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let transLeaf of transLeafTmp" class="animated zoomIn">
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <i class="icon" [style.background-color]="transLeaf.bgColor"><img src="{{transLeaf.categoryIcon}}"></i>
    </ion-avatar>
      <p>{{transLeaf.narration}}</p>
          <h3>heading</h3>
          <ion-note item-right class="transValue">
             <h2 test111</h2>
          </ion-note>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

HeyHey!
I didn't try but I think it should work! Good luck! ;)

**HTML**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let transLeaf of transLeafTmp;" [class.animated]="transLeaf.isAnimated" class="zoomIn">
  <ion-avatar item-left>
      <i class="icon" [style.background-color]="transLeaf.bgColor"><img src="{{transLeaf.categoryIcon}}"></i>
  </ion-avatar>
  <p>{{transLeaf.narration}}</p>
  <h3>heading</h3>
  <ion-note item-right class="transValue">
    <h2 test111</h2>
    </ion-note>
</ion-item>
```

**TypeScript** :

```
private ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.animateTransLeaf();
}

private animateTransLeaf(){
  let i = -1;

  while (++i < this.transLeafTmp.length) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.transLeafTmp[i].isAnimated = true;
    }, 50 * i);
  }
}
```